# Why was Theseus at the Rally?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Having just seen *The Crimes of Grindelwald* I find myself confused as to why Theseus and his Auror team were at

> Grindelwald's Rally at the Lestrange family tomb in Paris.

I thought Theseus worked as an Auror for the *British* Ministry of Magic?  Wouldn't there be a jurisdictional issue, and a potential international incident?

Was Theseus part of some sort of British-French joint task force?  I don't recall this ever being mentioned, but I suppose I might have missed it.

Comment: I'm not certain that audiences would have warmed to a series of long meetings where they discuss inter-ministry cooperation initiatives and jurisdictional boundaries.

Comment: @Valorum, if it was directed by George Lucas, it could have been a blockbuster. :-)  But seriously, they could have (and may have, for all I know) explained things by simply describing the task force, in passing, by name.  (Come to think of it, when Theseus and company were at Hogwarts I think they did drop a name, in response to being told they couldn't just barge in like that.  I *think* that was just something like "we work for the Ministry" though?  If it was "Ministries" or something that would pretty much confirm your answer ...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Theseus and Leta were shown to be operating out of the French Ministry in an earlier scene. Their boss, Travers, shows up a few scenes later and starts ordering them around.

> INT. MINISTÈRE DES AFFAIRES MAGIQUES, MAIN LEVEL—NIGHT
>   **THESEUS exits a meeting room** and strides toward LETA, who is waiting for him.
>   **LETA:** *What’s happening?*
>   **THESEUS:** *Grindelwald’s rallying. **We** don’t know where, but **we** think it’s tonight.*

I think it's fair to say that given the large number of aurors (50+) that show up later in the film that this was a *multi-jurisdictional taskforce* operating within France but under the general authority of what Kama refers to as the  ...

> "*Ministries of Europe*"

... for the purposes of defeating a Europe-wide threat. Grindelwald represents an existential threat to the whole wizarding world and is alleged to have committed crimes across the continent, largely ignoring borders and boundaries. That being that case, it would seem wise for Aurors from a range of countries to work together.

> **SPIELMAN:** *Six months are enough. It’s time for him to answer for his crimes **in Europe.***

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Do we know the name and/or position of the man who ordered Theseus to arrest everyone found at the rally?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - That would be **TRAVERS:** *"I’m the Head of Magical Law Enforcement"*

Comment: Thanks.  It seems a *little* odd to me that the British Head of Magical Law Enforcement would be allowed to give orders to a multi-jurisdictional taskforce, particularly given that (according to the original series) Grindelwald never operated in Britain.  But perhaps Travers was put in charge for that very reason, as a neutral party without an axe of his own to grind, or perhaps he was ignoring the line of command when he spoke to Theseus and Lita, I don't think it would be out of character.  Either way I guess it works.  I'll wait the usual 24 hours, but I think I can accept this answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - This film seems to treat Europe as a single country, something that JKR has been accused of when describing Africa.

Comment: Well, I suppose there's no particular reason why the wizard nations should have the same borders as Muggle nations.  Not sure how well the idea of a unified Europe fits in with the original series though, the idea of a multi-national task force sounds better to me.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - It's pretty clear that France has its own sovereign Ministry but the film acts as if it's just a place to have a confrontation with the baddie.

Comment: @HarryJohnston There probably is a *lot* of international magical cooperation in the light of the recently concluded Great War; the war clearly left a huge impression on wizards and non-magical people alike as we see from Grindelwald's use of it as a boogieman during the rally. Cooperation especially seems expected when tracking/fighting the magical equivalent of Hitler.